# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (2048, 256, 3)

Tags: arrays, shapes

```
def create_test_data():
    for i in range(len(image)):
        print('-'*9)
        print("Creating testing images...")
        print('-'*9)
        print(image[i])
        
        
test_data_path = '/home/motmot/Documents/unet/data/test/img/'
test_mask_path = '/home/motmot/Documents/unet/data/test/msk/'
image = os.listdir(test_data_path)
mask = os.listdir(test_mask_path)
total = len(image)
imgs = np.ndarray((total, image_rows, image_cols, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
#imgs = np.asarray((total, image_rows, image_cols, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
imgs_mask = np.ndarray((total, image_rows, image_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
#imgs_mask = np.asarray((total, image_rows, image_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
   
create_test_data()
```

I am using U-Net architecture network to segment my image data.

Since my input image data is M x N x 3, but the dimension is not the same as 256 x 256 x 3.

I have tried to change the codes into:

```
#imgs = np.asarray((total, image_rows, image_cols, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
#imgs_mask = np.asarray((total, image_rows, image_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
```